# Formatting attribute output in MB without bytes in parentheses

Tags: powershell, scripting, formatting, number-formatting

I have written a script that gathers information from public folders and outputs it to a .csv. All is well, except for the fact that the pf.FolderSize attribute is displayed (exported) in both MB and KB with the bytes in parenthesis e.g: 1.925 MB (2,018,497 bytes). I would like to sum the whole thing so it would be nice to format the results in MB only without the parenthesis, so I can easily get the overall size of all folders.

Here is the working

```
$publicFolders = Get-PublicFolder "\SomePublicFolderName" -Recurse -resultsize unlimited | 
Select-Object *
### Array to contain results
$results = @()
### Loop through and do the work
$publicFolders |ForEach-Object {
    $pf    = $_
    if ($pf.MailEnabled){
    $pfstat = Get-PublicFolderStatistics -Identity $pf.Identity | Where-Object {$_.User -notmatch "Default|Anonymous|S-X-X-XX"}
    $perms = Get-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity $pf.Identity | Where-Object {$_.User -notmatch "Default|Anonymous|S-X-X-XX"} 
Foreach($perm in $perms){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PFName = $pf.Name
        PFIdentity =  $pf.Identity
        MailEnabled = $pf.MailEnabled
        FolderSize = $pf.FolderSize
        TotalItemSize = $pfstat.TotalItemSize
        ItemCount = $pfstat.ItemCount
        LastModificationTime = $pfstat.LastModificationTime
        UserWithPerms  = $perm.User
        AccessRights   = $perm | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AccessRights
        PrimaryAddy =  $mepf.PrimarySmtpAddress
        ForwardingAddy = $mepf.ForwardingAddress
    }
}
}}| Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation -append
```

I have tried the below code, but the output was the same value for everything, so that can't be correct...

```
$pfstat = Get-PublicFolderStatistics -Identity $pf.Identity | Where-Object {$_.User -notmatch "Default|Anonymous|S-X-X-XX"} | Select-Object FolderPath,ItemCount,LastModificationTime @{
    N = "TotalItemSize (MB)";
    E = {
        "{0:N2}" -f ((($_.TotalItemSize -replace "[0-9\.]+ [A-Z]* \(([0-9,]+) bytes\)","`$1") -replace ",","") / 1MB)
    }
}
```

As always, Thanks in advance. I am eager to see where I went amiss with it.

Comment: If you inspect one example of `$pf.FolderSize` it looks exactly as `1.925 MB (2,018,497 bytes)` for example?

Comment: Your RegEx works for me, but you are missing a `,` in the `Select-Object` statement, after `LastModificationTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference if you run your code on the server itself or from your pc.
When running on (an older Exchange) server, `TotalItemSize` may not be a `[string]`, but a `[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Unlimited]` object instead which has a `.Value` property of type `[ByteQuantifiedSize]`.

To also handle that, use a helper function

```
function Format-MailboxStatisticsSize($itemSize) {
    if ($itemSize -is [string]) {
        '{0:F2}' -f (($itemSize -replace '^.*\(([\d,]+) bytes\)', '$1' -replace '\D') / 1MB)
    }
    else {   # Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Unlimited
        '{0:F2}' -f ($itemSize.Value.ToBytes() / 1Mb)
    }
}

Format-MailboxStatisticsSize $pfstat.TotalItemSize  # "1.925 MB (2,018,497 bytes)" --> 1.92
```

Comment: Ok, this looks good. Testing.

Comment: Genuis. Works like a charm.